# JQuery Mobile: selectmenu(),native-menu=false,<option> with placeholder added thru JS throws: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to add a `<option data-placeholder=true>placeholder value</option>` through JavaScript to an existing JQuery Mobile `selectmenu()`.

I had it working with no placeholder as shown in that JSFiddle (version 8): http://jsfiddle.net/nyluje/jg5cgw76/8/

In order to add a placeholder, I added the following lines at the beginning of my function `flipswitchChangesSingleSelToMultipleSel`:

```
targetSelect = $('body').find('select[id='+selectContainerId+']');

if($(targetSelect).find('[data-placeholder="true"]').length==0){
  phOption = document.createElement('option');
  $(phOption).attr('data-placeholder','true');
    $(phOption).text("Do a choice");
    $(targetSelect).prepend(phOption);       }
```

I updated the JSFiddle to a new version with it (version 9):
http://jsfiddle.net/nyluje/jg5cgw76/9/

The placeholder "Do a choice" does show up as expected, but when the choice is done, it displays: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'" in the debug console.

I looked around, and it seems to be a common issue, and solutions suggest to solve it by adding `listview().listview('refresh')`. So I've tried to grab on the DOM the `<ul>` element: `<ul class="ui-selectmenu-list ui-listview" id="select-menu" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="select-button">` and to apply to it `listview().listview('refresh')` but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, I've updated the JSFiddle (version 10): http://jsfiddle.net/nyluje/jg5cgw76/10/

I added: `selectmenu()` **before** the code regarding the placeholder and `selectmenu('refresh')` **after** it:

```
targetSelect.selectmenu();

if($(targetSelect).find('[data-placeholder="true"]').length==0){
  phOption = document.createElement('option');
  $(phOption).attr('data-placeholder','true');
    $(phOption).text("Do a choice");
    $(targetSelect).prepend(phOption);
 }

targetSelect.selectmenu('refresh');
```